# Using mockito any() throws java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.mockito.Matchers tried to access private method

Tags: mockito

I'm facing the exception

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.mockito.Matchers tried to access private method 'void org.mockito.internal.progress.ThreadSafeMockingProgress.()' (org.mockito.Matchers and org.mockito.internal.progress.ThreadSafeMockingProgress are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

> at org.mockito.Matchers.(Matchers.java:107)

when I try to use the matcher any() in mockito when() stub call. The class argument type is for "NewOrder" from the binance spot java library [here](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/binance/api/client/domain/account/NewOrder.java)

I'm trying to do

```
when(mockBinanceApiRestClient.newOrder(any(NewOrder.class))).thenReturn(buyOrderResp);
```

mocking the [BinanceApiRestClient](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/binance/api/client/BinanceApiRestClient.java).
The any() and when() are static imports from org.mockito.Mockito.
This is such a nightmare why it wouldn't work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you have two conflicting versions of Mockito on your classpath.

[ThreadSafeMockingProgress was converted to a singleton back in 2016](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/commit/c5f1bba0b77a86bbb06da1d159b62cfd290cea93#diff-3c33301ec5eb08aa1baf7aa7742ca45c8986314a3290465a2b069102071da9ab), and its constructor was changed to private.

On the other hand, you seem to be using `org.mockito.Matchers`,
which was deprecated for a long while and finally removed in Mockito 4.x

Answer (score 12):

I also faced similar issue when we used below dependency -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

we had below import statements which were causing IllegalAccess exception

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
```

I replaced Matchers with ArgumentMatchers as below -

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
```

This resolved the issue.